# Cannot exclude element from string

Tags: jquery

I have a paragraph of text and I need to wrap each group of words (comma separated) in a span tag so I can animate them when hovered on... easy enough. I need to do this to everything except the "a#close". I have tried using the ":not" selector but can't seem to get it to work as desired.

HTML

```
<div id="stuff"><p>Words Words Words, Words Words Words, Words Words Words, Words Words
Words, Words Words Words, Words Words Words, Words Words Words,
<a href="#" id="close">Close</a></p></div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $('#stuff:not(a#close)').each(function(){
    var text = $(this).html().split(','),
        len = text.length,
        result = []; 

    for( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
      result[i] = '<span>' + text[i] + '</span>';
    }
    $(this).html(result.join(' '));
});
```

I can make it work as desired by changing the html mark up and putting the a#close in a p tag with a different ID, but would like to understand the :not selector better, that is if it is the right one to use.
thank you

Comment: This might help http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/nBCQA/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `a#close` is a child of the container. You could select all nodes and then filter:

```
$('#stuff *').filter(':not(a#close)').each(function(){
var text = $(this).html().split(','),
        len = text.length,
        result = []; 

    for( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
      result[i] = '<span>' + text[i] + '</span>';
    }
    $(this).html(result.join(' '));
})
```

You could also use a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function there to avoid the loop:

```
var result = text.map(function(text){
    return '<span>' + text + '</span>';
});
```

Comment: This also wraps <a> in <span>

Comment: agreed, still wraps <a> in <span>. appreciate the help though.

Answer (score 2):

`$('#stuff:not(a#close)')` selects all elements with the id `stuff`, except for those who also match the selector `a#close`. So really, the `:not` isn't doing anything in this case. Consider using `.contents()`

```
var words = [];
$('#stuff p').contents(':not(a#close)').each(function() {
  words.push($(this).text().split(','));
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
// "words" is now an array of the comma separated strings.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s9K7W/

Of course, this is sort of abstracted. In your case you'd modify what is being done in the `.each()` function to split and wrap the text nodes.

Comment: I like this solution, I'm going to try and make it work in the .each() function. thx man.